# Delete and send to another entity Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a little trouble with the entity's.

I want to delete an item, but the content from this item must be send to another entity.
The content in this entity comes from a form, id, name, lastname and time. Those items must be send to another entity like a backup.

My delete function works

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/delete/{id}", defaults={"id"=""}, name="delete")
 */
public function delete($id ){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $reservation = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Applicant')->find($id);
       if($reservation != null){
            $em->remove($reservation);
            $em->flush();
        }
    return new response('verwijderd');
}
```

but now the problem, i want to send the content to an other entity. But i dont have any clue how to do this.

And after a lot of searching on the web i am still desperate for an answer.

Thank you!

Comment: What does `content` represents? Single property or more than one? What do you mean by `send`? You want to update different entity with the data from this one or something else? Please, be a bit more specific about your problem.

Comment: The content in this entity comes from a form, id, name, lastname and time. Those items must be send to another entity like a backup.

Answer (score 0):

[FIXED]

I didnt think straight here is the solution.

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/delete/{id}", defaults={"id"=""}, name="delete")
 */
public function delete($id ){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $reservation = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Applicant')->find($id);

       if($reservation != null){

           $del = new ApplicantDelete();

           $del->setRoom($reservation->getRoom());
           $del->setName($reservation->getName());
           $del->setLastName($reservation->getLastName());
           $del->setDate($reservation->getDate());
           $del->setTimeStart($reservation->getTimeStart());
           $del->setTimeEnd($reservation->getTimeEnd());
           $del->setToken($reservation->getToken());

            $em->persist($del);
            $em->remove($reservation);
            $em->flush();

        }
    return new response();
}
```